How to consolidate slowing changing dimension tables using sql, python or r?
I have below input table:



id
type
value
date_from
date_to




1
department
finance
2020-01-01
9999-12-31


1
headcount
10
2020-01-01
2020-02-03


1
headcount
15
2020-02-04
9999-12-31


1
location
DC
2020-01-01
2020-01-21


1
location
NY
2020-01-22
9999-12-31



I want to convert it to a wide table containing all "type" fields as columns:



id
department
headcount
location
date_from
date_to




1
finance
10
DC
2020-01-01
2020-01-21


1
finance
10
NY
2020-01-22
2020-02-03


1
finance
15
NY
2020-02-04
9999-12-31



Note that my actual data has multiple "id" and unknown "type" values. How can I achieve this effectively using either sql, python or r?
Edit
The final output represents a historic table which will enable me to go back to any given day to view the status on that day.
In my example, "department" is always "finance". "headcount" and "location" have changed, so that there are two new rows.

That sure sounds like a reshape/pivot operation. Probably pivot_table().

@NickODell yes but I could not think of a way to properly compare the dates when pivoting to columns

How do you match headcount with location? For example, how do you know headcount=15 corresponds to location=NY (and not location=DC)?

@cottontail it is based on the date. Headcount 15 is starting from date 02-04 which only applied location NY (NY is after date 01-22

IIUC, here's one approach (python / pandas):

Change column 'date_from' to datetime values with pd.to_datetime.
Apply df.pivot, chaining df.ffill and df.reset_index.
Now, distinguish between groups in column 'id' using Series.ne and Series.shift and rebuild column 'date_to' using a shifted version of 'date_from' minus 1 day (using pd.DateOffset) to which we apply Series.mask in order to add a final future date per group.
Add rebuilt 'date_to' with df.assign and get the columns in order with df.loc.

Note that '9999-12-31' is way above the acceptable max timestamp (cf. pd.Timestamp.max, a moving target). E.g., let's do '2200-12-31'.
Code
# based on adjusted `df` below
import pandas as pd

df['date_from'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_from'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

out = (
    df.pivot(index=['id', 'date_from'], columns=['type'], values='value')
    .ffill()
    .reset_index()
)

cond = out['id'].ne(out['id'].shift(-1))

cols = ['id'] + df['type'].unique().tolist() + ['date_from', 'date_to']

out = (
    out.assign(
        date_to=(out['date_from'] - pd.DateOffset(days=1))
        .shift(-1)
        .mask(cond=cond, other=pd.Timestamp('2200-12-31'))
    )
    .loc[:, cols]
)

Output
   id department headcount location  date_from    date_to
0   1    finance        10       DC 2020-01-01 2020-01-21
1   1    finance        10       NY 2020-01-22 2020-02-03
2   1    finance        15       NY 2020-02-04 2200-12-31
3   2  marketing        10       DC 2020-01-01 2020-01-21
4   2  marketing        10       NY 2020-01-22 2020-02-03
5   2  marketing        15       NY 2020-02-04 2200-12-31

Data used
Adding a second 'id' with a different department:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1},
    'type': {0: 'department', 1: 'headcount', 2: 'headcount', 
             3: 'location', 4: 'location'},
    'value': {0: 'finance', 1: '10', 2: '15', 3: 'DC', 4: 'NY'},
    'date_from': {0: '2020-01-01', 1: '2020-01-01', 2: '2020-02-04', 
                  3: '2020-01-01', 4: '2020-01-22'},
    'date_to': {0: '9999-12-31', 1: '2020-02-03', 2: '9999-12-31', 
                3: '2020-01-21', 4: '9999-12-31'}
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = pd.concat([df, df.assign(id=2, value=df.value.replace('finance','marketing'))], 
               ignore_index=True)

df

   id        type      value   date_from     date_to
0   1  department    finance  2020-01-01  9999-12-31
1   1   headcount         10  2020-01-01  2020-02-03
2   1   headcount         15  2020-02-04  9999-12-31
3   1    location         DC  2020-01-01  2020-01-21
4   1    location         NY  2020-01-22  9999-12-31
5   2  department  marketing  2020-01-01  9999-12-31
6   2   headcount         10  2020-01-01  2020-02-03
7   2   headcount         15  2020-02-04  9999-12-31
8   2    location         DC  2020-01-01  2020-01-21
9   2    location         NY  2020-01-22  9999-12-31

